# Trouble compiling AIR for iOS using ADT

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm fairly new to AIR. I'm developing an app for Android and iOS that uses some ANEs (Milkman's GoViral, AdMob, GoogleServices). They're all supposedly compatible across platforms. 
My app works perfectly on Android, but completely crashes when I install it on an iPad. It shows a black screen and crashes two seconds after. Anyone got any ideas?

This is the command line I'm using: -package -target ipa-test -storetype pkcs12 -keystore blablabla.p12 -provisioning-profile blablabla.mobileprovision bla.ipa bla-app.xml bla.swf languajes.xml resources -extdir exDir

Any help on this matter would be GREATLY appreciated. I have zero knowledge about iOS or any Apple product. Thank you!

Comment: You should start by compiling without anes and see what happens then compile with one, etc ... so you can then see which ane is causing the trouble if any. Don't assume just get some proof.

Comment: Forgot to mention I actually tried that. Removed all ANEs, compiled again, made sure it still worked on Android just in case I had missed something, still didn't work on iOS. Sorry.